# hex string to decimal not working-something is incorrect: swift

Tags: swift

I have a small piece of code as shown below:

```
var str = "42042753 08b14f00 1852003f 8a86"
var bre = str.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: advance(str.startIndex, 0), end: advance(str.endIndex, -29)))
if bre == "42" {
    var batt = str.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: advance(str.startIndex, 2), end: advance(str.endIndex, -25)))
    println("\(batt)")
    let value = UInt8(strtoul(batt, nil, 16))
    println("\(value)")
}
```

All I am trying to do is check if first two characters are "42" and if so, convert the next four characters i.e., "0427" to decimal "value" and it is not working. I tested `let value = UInt8(strtoul("ff", nil, 16))` and it works properly and prints "255". so why isn't "batt" which is "0427" converted? what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is problem  UInt8 max number is 1024. 0427 = 1063 > 1024. so it not work.
change to this:

```
  let value = Int(strtoul(batt, nil, 16))
```

Comment: this fixed the problem, thanks. What if I want to convent "003f 8a68" into decimal? Do I have to use Int32?

Comment: Yes,have to use Int32. 003f8a68 = 4164200  and :  INT16_MAX = 32767 . INT32_MAX = 2147483647

Comment: On a 32-bit platform, Int is the same size as Int32.
On a 64-bit platform, Int is the same size as Int64.